# implementing counting semaphore using java

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I suspect the significant difference between mutex and semaphore is that counting semaphore supports maximum access more than one since mutext only supports at most one access at one time.

But when doing the implementation as follows;

```
public class countingSemaphore{
 private static final int _MOSTTABLES = 3;  // whatever maximum number
 private static int availtable = _MOSTTABLES;

 public synchronized static void Wait(){  
  while(availtable==0){  
   try{
    wait();    
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  availtable--;  
 }

 public synchronized static void Signal(){
  while(availtable==_MOSTTABLES){
   try{
    wait();
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  availtable++;  
 }
}
```

the problem is the calling of non-static wait() method of object. But, I have to apply synchronization to class instead of instances of objects since accessing is shared among multiple instances.

How to resolve the wait() error? Do we have another method in java or we have to implement wait() ourselves?

Comment: Are you aware that there is already `Semaphore` and `CountdownLatch` classes in `java.util.concurrent`, or are you re-implementing this stuff for homework?

Comment: most likely homework , unless you are doing java in a restricted env which disallowed the concurrent stuff and have to implement it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you are looking for a Semaphore (which initialized with one permit, behaves equivalent to a Mutex).

If you cannot use J2SE 5.0, then I would suggest to check out it's predecessor [util.concurrent](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html), which is in Public Domain and can be backported/used on Java versions before J2SE 5.0 (I have used some derived classes on limited devices as well).

Take a look at the [Semaphore](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and it's order providing derivative classes, e.g. [FIFOSemaphore](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/FIFOSemaphore.html).

If you need guidance and a reference for the bookshelf, I recommend ["Concurrent Programming in Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090), by Doug Lea, who was responsible for [util.concurrent](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html) and the JSR that brought us java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great many other issues to deal with here (if you are trying to implement a concurrency control object) but one solution to your specific issue of how to use a wait/notify mechanism for a static level construct is simply to untangle the notion of a monitor from the construct:  you use the static methods of your class but synchronization is performed on a specific instance of an object (any object) that is referenced by the static methods.  For example:

```
public class MySemaphore {
   // ...
   private final Object lock = new Object();

   public static void acquire(int count) {
       while( ...) {
          synchronized(lock) {
              lock.wait();
          }
       }
   }
   public static void release(int count) {
       while( ...) {
          synchronized(lock) {
              lock.notifyAll();
          }
       }
   }
}
```